# Access Violation On Vista Startup

Tags: .net, access-violation, unhandled-exception

I occasionally get a strange unhandled access violation when my .NET application is started automatically on startup (using a shortcut in the "Startup" folder) by Windows Vista.  I have not seen this error when I start the executable manually.  It happens randomly and I have yet to be able to reproduce the issue reliably.

Here's the message I get:

> Unhandled exception at 0x6f303dea in
>   {executable name}.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location
>   0x0000000c.

Call stack:

> mscorwks.dll!6f303dea()
>   [Frames
>   below may be incorrect and/or missing,
>   no symbols loaded for mscorwks.dll]
>   kernel32.dll!7780907a()
>   mscoree.dll!6ff47c24()
>   kernel32.dll!7780d0e9()
>   ntdll.dll!778e19bb()
>   ntdll.dll!778e198e()

Since mscorwks.dll is related to the CLR, I think this might be a bug in the CLR.  Any ideas on why this might be happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended that you use WER to collect process crash dump. Please select Full Dump option and then you can use WinDBG to debug the dump.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181(VS.85).aspx

Or if you like you can consult Microsoft support team via http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: Thanks!  I just added the WER registry keys (they were not on my computer) and I will let you know how it works when my application crashes next time.